# Where to specify PHP version that should be used in Apache for CentOS?

Tags: php, apache, centos, centos7

Using CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core). I just updated PHP from 5.6.27 to 5.6.30. If I create the typical phpinfo file and view from browser I'm seeing 5.6.27 while php -v returns 5.6.30. I know that I'm supposed to specify within Apache which version to use but I can't seem to locate specific directions on just how to do that. How do I tell Apache which PHP version to use?

Comment: Have you restarted Apache after you updated PHP? Most probably PHP is loaded as an Apache module and you have to restart Apache to make it load the new version.

Comment: I have but unfortunately that was not the resolution. Tested on both a staging and production environment and neither reflected the change in phpinfo.

Comment: How was PHP installed in the first place? If it is compiled from source you need to specify it to also compile the apache module. If it's FPM you need to specify to apache to use the new FPM service (if any). If it is FPM restarting the FPM service may also be needed.

Comment: JK now it works.... That was weird. RESTARTING APACHE WAS THE FIX. Must have been cached or something as to why I didn't see the result.